# Allow duplicate IDs to display in a Grid - Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I have a grid that is populated with records returned from an ajax `request`. When I exclude the `id` field from the model, all my results display properly (*minus the id*):

```
var model = Ext.define('Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name   : 'name',       mapping     : 'element.name',   type    : 'auto'}, 
        {name   : 'uid',        mapping     : 'element.uid',    type    : 'auto'},
        //{name : 'id',         mapping     : 'element.attributes[0].attrvalue',    type    : 'auto'},
```

However, I can't include this field without truncating hundreds of records. From what I understand, Ext does not allow for duplicate IDs. In my grid, it is necessary to display multiple of the same IDs.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set idProperty of you Model to something else. The Default value is 'id'. This field is used as unique identifier of models.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is silly. It was as easy as changing the name : `'id'` to anything *besides* `'id'`:

```
{name : 'elementId',  mapping : 'element.attributes[0].attrvalue',  type : 'auto'}
```

And of course matching that to the grid:

```
{header : 'ID', dataIndex : 'elementId'}
```

I suppose there is reason to keep unique IDs for each record in an `Ext.Store`, just like any other set of data/database. It just wasn't apparent that `id` was a keyword in the framework that must be unique in every store's record.